# Inherit dictionary for multiple levels of ancestry

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I have a number of classes all inheriting from each other, and each class needs to provide some dictionary items to the `definitions` attribute.

For instance:

```
class A(object):
    definitions = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.definitions = {}
        self.definitions.get_parent_definitions()
        self.definitions.update(self.get_definitions())

    def get_parent_definitions(self):
        if self.__class__ != A:
             self.definitions.update(
                 super(self.__class__, self).get_parent_definitions())
        self.definitions.update(self.get_definitions())

    def get_definitions(self):
        return {
            'A' : 1,
        }

class B(A) :
    def get_definitions(self):
        return {
            'B' : 22,
        }

class CA(B):
    def get_definitions(self):
        return {
            'C' : 333,
        }

class CB(B):
    def get_definitions(self):
        return {
            'C' : 444,
        }
```

This results in the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp` unsurprisingly.

The ultimate objective is that I'm left with the following definitions:

```
CA.definitions = {
     'A' : 1,
     'B' : 22,
     'C' : 333,
}

CB.definitions = {
     'A' : 1,
     'B' : 22,
     'C' : 444,
}
```

The main purpose of arranging the code this way is to try and avoid needing to call `super` in any sub-classes of `A` as I'm anticipating needing quite a lot of sub-classes. Is this possible?

Comment: None of the classes in your example code inherit from each other.

Comment: Oopsidoodle! Fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't sure I understood you properly, but perhaps it's what you mean:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.definitions = self.get_all_definitions()

    @classmethod
    def get_all_definitions(cls):
        dct = {}
        while True:
            dct.update(cls.get_definitions())
            if cls == A:
                return dct
            else:
                cls = cls.__bases__[0] # only first parent class is considered
                                       # multiple inheritance is not supported

    @classmethod
    def get_definitions(cls):
        return {'A' : 1}

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def get_definitions(cls):
        return {'B' : 22}

class CA(B):
    @classmethod
    def get_definitions(cls):
        return {'C' : 333}

class CB(B):
    @classmethod
    def get_definitions(cls):
        return {'C' : 444}

# Test
ca = CA()
print ca.definitions

cb = CB()
print cb.definitions
```

If definitions for all classes are hard coded, you can make it class attributes instead of methods.

```
class CB(B):
    cls_definitions = {'C' : 444}
```

and replace this:

```
            dct.update(cl.get_definitions())
```

with this:

```
            dct.update(cl.cls_definitions)
```